# finding a point away from d distance orthogonaly from a given 3D line

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, geometry

> I want to find the coordinate of a point (say P) which is away from a known distance (say d). 
>   the case is: I want the point that lie on a line (3d) which is perpendicular to the another given 
>   line segment (3d) and passing through the one end of that given line segment (say A). 
>   So, I know 2 end points (also vector along the line) of the given line segment and distance d and vector of the perpendicular line.  Also point C where the perpendicular line pass through is also 
>   known.
>   I am having `vector3` class and line3 class.

the method to tackle this problem is difficult to figure out, so please help me in this regard by showing the way.

Yes, as there are 2 points on that line in opposit direction, I am looking for the point (P), which is closer to point C (not the Q).

thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: this problem is underspecified

Comment: @sellibitze: i am really poor in vector cases. please help me.. should I explain the question clearly or what should i do?

Comment: Firstly, explain what exactly you mean by "perpendicular distance". What does this mean in case of a point and a line *segment* (a line segment has end points, a line has not -- the shortest connection between a point and a line segment is not necessarily perpendicular to the line). Secondly, there are lots of possible solutions. It's not clear what solution you are interested in. Do you want just any solution of all the possible ones or a specific one?

Comment: @sellibitze: i got,, i am updating the post. thanks

Comment: There's not one single point that has distance d and is perpendicular to a line in 3D. There's an infinite number of points because a) you can rotate the point around the line without changing its distance while keeping it at the same time perpendicular and b) you can move the whole problem along the line towards A or B.

Comment: @g_niro: note that in 3d the solution to the problem as presented is a circle rather than a point (or even a cylinder since you didn't specify that the distance is calculated from a specific point on the line, but it's reasonable to assume that point is fixed). You need more constraints to obtain a single point.

Comment: dear all,, yes it is my mistake of presenting the actual question in a n undestable way.. i update it now.. hope it would ok..now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find direction vector then multiply it by `d` then add to start point:

```
Vector A, C;
float d = 100;

Vector dir = C - A;
dir.normalize();
dir *= d;
Vector P = A + dir;
```

Comment: thank you.. to know, i want to ask: I want point P and not the point Q. So, does your method give point P?

Comment: I think `dir` should be `dir = C - A`, to get the direction from `A` to `C`.

Comment: thanks all.. was struggling too long to figure out..